# Bootstrap 3 Can't center divs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to center three rows of three images: http://secondary.makeminechocolate.org/young-kids

The code for one of the rows is:

```
<div class="container text-center">

  <!-- ...bunch of other code here.... -->

  <div class="row col-sm-12 margin-bottom-xs col-centered">
    <div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 margin-bottom-xs regRabbitB-sm">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/sites/default/files/2018-02/Lang.png" />
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 boyRabbit-xs boyRabbit-sm">
        <img alt="Rabbit On Boy" class="img-responsive"  src="/sites/default/files/2018-02/Exelby.png" />
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 margin-bottom-xs margin-left5-xs regRabbitR-sm">
        <img alt="Rabbit and Child in Box" class="img-responsive" src="/sites/default/files/2018-02/West.png" />
      </div>
    </div> <!-- centered div -->
  </div> <!-- row -->

  <!-- ...more code here.... -->

</div> <!-- container -->
```

This is the style for my own centering class:

```
.col-centered {
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: auto;
}
```

I know it's something simple but I've tried creating my own centering class and just using `text-center` but nothing works.

Comment: There's a built-in helper class for centering blocks: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-center

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the bootstrap `col-*` classes with the `.regRabbitR-sm .boyRabbit-sm` classes. Try moving those to the `<img>` tag. Also images will be center with `text-center` class in relation to their respective parent. You shouldn't use custom margin classes with `col-*` since it will mess with the responsive grid.

ex:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 text-center">
<img alt="Rabbit On Boy" class="boyRabbit-xs boyRabbit-sm img-responsive"  src="/sites/default/files/2018-02/Exelby.png" />
</div>
```

If you want them to be evenly spaced you could try with `display: flex;`

```
<div class="flex-img-wrapper">
<img href="img1" />
<img href="img2" />
<img href="img3" />
</div>

.flex-img-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, everyone. It now looks like it's centering by stretching out the spacing of the images so the left image is on the left margin and the right image is on the right margin. What I want is to preserve the spacing I have assigned and have the three images spaced evenly with equal spacing from the left and right margins. .

Comment: check this using the `display: flex;` attribute https://codepen.io/parredondov/pen/XZQmLK you can uncomment and comment to see all available spacing options and choose the one that fits your needs

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure the total columns add up to 12.  Also, if you want the middle image to take up 100% of the column width, you will need to create a helper class for that in Bootstrap 3.

```css
.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row margin-bottom-xs">
    <div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 text-center margin-bottom-xs regRabbitB-sm">
        <img alt="Rabbit with Child" class="w-100 img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x225" />
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 boyRabbit-xs boyRabbit-sm">
        <img alt="Rabbit On Boy" class="w-100 img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/169x225" />
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 margin-bottom-xs margin-left5-xs regRabbitR-sm">
        <img alt="Rabbit and Child in Box" class="w-100 img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x225" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- centered div -->
  </div>
</div>
```